# Implement QR Code X-dimension in PHP

Tags: php, qr-code

We were using bartender for QR code printing: 
http://www.seagullscientific.com/aspx/free-bar-code-label-printing-software-download.aspx

in BarTender we can specify x-dimension of QR code

[image: QR code with x-dimension]

I am using following library to generate QR code.
http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-qr-code-generator-class.htm

But it uses google charts for generating QR code and i am unable to find option of x-dimension in google chart.

So now i want to implement this x-dimension functionality in PHP.

Please guide me if there is any open source solution available or if there is any paid solution.

**[Edit]**
Please consider following data as sample to generate QR code.

123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789
123456789123456789123456789

Comment: could it be chs=<width>x<height> in google?

Comment: may be, but if it is; then what width and height should be used to have 5.8 mils x-dimension.

Comment: Mils are very large... DPI too using Google API to do that you will be very limited. You probably need a open source solution. Probably going to need a code snippet to convert pixels to mils... or pixels to dpi and dpi to mils. http://www.barcodemaking.com/barm_barcode_resolution_size_mils.html

Comment: Can you mention any open source or paid solution for this purpose, because i think Google API is limited.

Comment: Well i see you are using PHP so http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ would be very good.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an [Open Source QR generator](https://github.com/edent/QR-Generator-PHP). You can specify exactly how many pixels wide you want the image to be.

So, you would write

`qr.php?d=YourCode&e=Q&t=J&size=500`

For a 500x500px code containing "YourCode".

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am trying to use it, but the image created cannot be viewed, can you guide plz

Comment: You just need to upload those files to a webserver. On mine, the URL would be http://shkspr.mobi/qr/php/qr.php?size=500&d=123456789123456789123456789

Comment: OK i got the error, my image and data paths were not correct!

Comment: Hey Terence, there is an issue, i am forced to generate qr code of size 40 x 40 only, but data is really large. I tried to create qr code of 40 x 40 with my specified data, it generates it but its not readable by our qr code scanner.

Comment: I need smaller code with larger data like 350 to 450 characters

Comment: That's not how QR codes work. The more data you put in to them, the larger or more complex they need to be. You could put a URL which points to the full data set if you wanted.